# Empty JSON POST response with jQuery but works with Curl

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, curl

i'm development an API for my Ruby on Rails site and i have a problem when i try to catch the responsed token with jQuery. With Curl works fine, but in jQuery not get any response.

Part of Rails Controller

```
render :status => 200, :json => { :token => @user.authentication_token }
```

Using Curl:

```
jorge@george:~/$ curl -F 'email=jorge@hola.com' -F 'password=12345' http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tokens.json

Response with:

{"token":"azScPXjgppqR1Q3cH82S"}
```

Using jQuery

```
function login() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/en/api/v1/tokens.json",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "email=jorge@hola.com&password=12345",
        crossDomain: "true",
        beforeSend: function () {
        // loading
        },
        success: function(data) {
        // finish load
            alert(data.message);
        },
        error: function(request, type, errorThrown) {
            alert(request.status + " " + request.statusText);
        }
    });

}
```

Using jQuery i get the alert "0 error", and firebug show an empty response. (32b size).

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you setting crossDomain to true?  This is used for a JSONP call not for a JSON call.  What happens if you remove that?

Comment: The urls aren't the same, one is to `en/api` the other is to `/api/`

Comment: I don't think you can use json for a cross domain request; have you tried json?

Comment: @mosch lol yeah typo my bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSONP request only allows GET method, so i change the routes on my api controller from POST to GET and it's works perfect.